# Disable accented character on iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, non-ascii-characters

I'm using swift to code and I'd like to disable the accented keyboard on iOS device when the user long presses on the character.

I dont want to do that in the Settings but by code.

I don't know if this topic has been discussed before.

Thank you

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I have flowing code in ShouldChangeCharacterInRange method

```
public func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool 
{ 
 let xField = fieldBy(textField.tag)! 
 let editedString = textField.text!.replace(range, with: string) 
 let isLengthValid = !xField.isBeyondLimit(editedString) 
 if isLengthValid { 
  xField.validate(editedString) 
 } 
return isLengthValid 
}
```

Comment: Try using keyboard type ASCIICapable

Comment: @LeoDabus, I've tried that but didnt fix it.

Comment: Using a custom keyboard via the inputView?

Comment: You can't control the keyboard, but you can allow/disable/modify what the user type. For instance, if the user types "é", you can transform it into "e" (it's a simple case, because for "æ", I don't know what it should be replaced with) or not allow that character.